# Get query with one distinct column, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

In `customer_names` I get an array of values, and from there I want to get only the first `created_at` value. With my current code I get multiple rows with all values from `customer_names`.

```
$query = $this->customer->newQuery()->select(
      'customers.id',
      'customers.sage_id',
      'customers.account_name',
      'customer_names.name as name',
      'customer_names.novation_date as novation_date',
    )->withCount('contracts');
$query->leftJoin('customer_names', 'customers.id', 'customer_names.customer_id')->groupBy('customers.sage_id');
```

Also I tried another approach, but I get a null array:

```
$query = $this->customer->newQuery()->with([
    'customerNames' => function ($query){
        $query->oldest()->first();
    }
])
```

> "SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column
> "customer_names.novation_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or
> be used in an aggregate

If I add this to groupBy and also the name and ID, I get no errors, but the result is the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn off sctrict mode in Laravel application.

go to `config/database.php`

under the MySQL set

```
strict => false
```

and it will start working.

Here is the database settings

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

### if you are using Postgres

Then you have to add all the columns to the group by which you have mentioned in the SELECT

```
$query = $this->customer->newQuery()->select(
      'customers.id',
      'customers.sage_id',
      'customers.account_name',
      'customer_names.name as name',
      'customer_names.novation_date as novation_date',
    )->withCount('contracts');
$query->leftJoin('customer_names', 'customers.id', 'customer_names.customer_id')->groupBy(['customers.sage_id', 'customers.account_name', 'name', 'novation_date']);
```

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL, and I don't have this.

Answer (score 0):

Error in left join please try below format

$query = customers::newQuery();

$query->select('customers.id','customers.sage_id','customers.account_name','customer_names.name as name','customer_names.novation_date as novation_date',)->withCount('contracts');

$query->leftJoin('customer_names', 'customer_names.id', '=' ,customers.customer_id')->groupBy('customers.sage_id');

if you need distinct column please  add distinct() method in your query

Comment: I tried this, and I get the same error. customers.id" must appear in the GROUP BY, and If I added, the response is not ok.